# How do you stop an Object from being destroyed in a loop in Unreal C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Below is my code:

```
void test::ParseGeoJson(const FString& File)
{
    FString JsonString; //Json converted to FString
    FFileHelper::LoadFileToString(JsonString, *File);
    TArray<TSharedPtr<FJsonValue>> RawJsonValueArray;
    TSharedRef<TJsonReader<>> Reader = TJsonReaderFactory<>::Create(*JsonString);
    bool success = FJsonSerializer::Deserialize(Reader, RawJsonValueArray);
    
    if (success)
    {
        TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> GeoJsonObject;
        
        for (int32 index = 0; index < RawJsonValueArray.Num(); index++)
        {
            GeoJsonObject =  RawJsonValueArray[index]->AsObject();
    
            TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> geometry = GeoJsonObject->GetObjectField("geometry");
            FString type = GeoJsonObject->GetStringField("type");
            TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> properties = GeoJsonObject->GetObjectField("properties");
            TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> layer = GeoJsonObject->GetObjectField("layer");
            FString source = GeoJsonObject->GetStringField("source");
        }
    }
}
```

The `GeoJsonObject` represents an object at that array index.
I then try to get the properties of the `GeoJsonObject`.  This does work sort of.

When my code moves to the next line that uses the `GeoJsonObject` such as `GeoJsonObject->GetStringField` the main `GeoJsonObject` seems to be destroyed.  In the example above I can get geometry and type.  However as soon as a get a value for type then the value of geometry throws error "parent address is invalid".

How do keep `GeoJsonObject` alive?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Unreal, but (in C++) the behaviour you see is consistent with `RawJsonValueArray[index]->AsObject()` returning an object by value, so the assignment in `GeoJsonObject =  RawJsonValueArray[index]->AsObject()` stores a reference/pointer to an object with lifetime that ends when the statement completes i.e. produces a dangling pointer/reference, so accessing its properties gives undefined behaviour.  [This is even more likely if the object type has, say, an `operator SomeType * ()` that allows implicit conversion of such an object to a pointer].

Comment: I figured it was something like that.  Any idea on a way to fix this?

Comment: It depends on why you think `GeoJsonObject` needs to have type `TSharedPtr<FJsonObject>` and what `RawJsonValueArray[index]->AsObject()` actually returns (I don't know).   I'm speculating, but one option is to define/initialise `GeoJsonObject` in the body of the loop (not outside).  For example (C++11 and later) `auto GeoJsonObject =  RawJsonValueArray[index]->AsObject()` (so `GeoJsonObject` is an object that will be created and destructed each iteration, and is possibly a copy not a wrapped pointer).  You might also need to use `.` rather than `->` to access its properties

Comment: How about static variable? Static variable will not destroy util program exit?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it did not work.  I found something that works but I am not sure if it is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new loop

I created a pointer * to a new Object created from my array
I then created a variable = to the new Object, calling Get which retrieved a reference.  From this point I can use my new variable without it being dereferenced.

```
for (int32 index = 0; index < RawJsonValueArray.Num(); index++)
        {
            
            TSharedPtr<FJsonObject>* JsonObject = new TSharedPtr<FJsonObject>(RawJsonValueArray[index]->AsObject());
            FJsonObject* GeoJsonObject = JsonObject->Get();

            TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> geometry = GeoJsonObject->GetObjectField("type");
            GLog->Log("asdfasdf");
            FString type = GeoJsonObject->GetStringField("type");
            TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> properties = GeoJsonObject->GetObjectField("properties");
            TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> layer = GeoJsonObject->GetObjectField("layer");
            FString source = GeoJsonObject->GetStringField("source");
        }
```